# Insert Primary key of Selected Drop down list value as a foreign key in another table using php mysql

Tags: php

I need to insert the selected value primary key to be inserted as a foreign key in another table but neither it gives error and nothing is happening
i have populated the drop down list with the below form

```
<form id="country" name="form1" method="post" action="datatodb.php">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
Select Country :<select name="countryname">
<?php
include 'dblogin.php';
// Get records from database (table "name_list").
$list=mysql_query("select * from _countries");
// Show records by while loop.
while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_list['countryid']; ?>"><?php echo $row_list['countryname']; ?></option>
<?php
// End while loop.
}
?>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td>
Add Location :   
<input type="text" name="locationname" value="" maxlength="40"/></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" size="20"/></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

With below code im capturing the Values and trying to insert the primary key of 
selected value in another table where it is a foreign key

```
<?php
include 'dblogin.php';

$countryid=$_POST['countryname']; 
$locationname=$_POST['locationname'];

$countryid = stripslashes($countryid); 
$locationname = stripslashes($locationname);

$countryid = mysql_real_escape_string($countryid);
$locationname = mysql_real_escape_string($locationname);

$sql="insert into _location (locationid, locationname, countryid) values ('NULL','".$locationname."','".$locationname."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Please help me in getting the selected value primary key and get inserted into another table where it is a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

if you make `locationid` as **auto increment** , you do not need to add this value
 to the query,

do like

```
    $sql="insert into _location (locationname, countryid) values 

('".$locationname."','".$countryid."')";
```

note : to ignore duplicate values of `locationname` , set this field as **unique**

**EDIT: you have a typo mistake, you try to insert `locationname` twice, i replace it**

Comment: Dear Haim still Nothing Get inserted Please all helpers understand i need to insert the selected value from drop down list primary key in another table as a foreign key

Comment: what error you get ? if (!mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";
}

Comment: no error but when i m selecting the table in mysql dos mode the table is empty

Comment: insert into _location (locationid, locationname, countryid) values ('NULL','".$locationname."','".$locationname."')";
to ----- insert into _location (locationid, locationname, countryid) values ('NULL','".$locationname."','".$countryid."')";

Comment: i m sorry but where is the sign to click

Comment: below the number '0' , When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: Ok i undertanda thanx again do u have a private chat area where we could meet